# <li> dots placed on wrong side of picture next to <li> in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a div with a picture in it, next to this is a div with some text including some lists (li) and the dots for the li's should be on the right side of the picture, but in IE11 it's shown in the div with the picture, on the left side.

Ive made a jsfiddle to explain it better here: http://jsfiddle.net/tD8an/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="pic">
        <img src="http://www.wallcore.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/funny_pic_of_a_monkey-280x280.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <b>HEADLINE</b>
        <ul>
            <li>Li 1</li>
            <li>Li 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
}
#pic {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
#text {
    width: 700px;
}
```

Is there any fix or something I can do? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Bullets appear to right of image (next to `li` text) in Chrome 31. They appear just inside left edge of image in IE11 for me. I inspected the DOM in both browsers, and your `div#text` element has its left edge being placed all the way on the left edge of the page (in both browsers) due to `div#pic` being floated. The text is kept on the right side of the image since that's how `float` works, but it looks like IE11 (didn't check other versions) has a bug with placement of list bullets next to floated content.

Comment: Any other ways i can do this, so it shows correct in IE11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you can do is changing the position of the bulletpoints to inside. I don't see any downsides here.

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Alternatively you could create a new *block formatting context* with overflow. But the text will not flow around the image then.

```
#text {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` is not a valid child element of `<p>`

Also, your widths are incorrect.

The container is 700px, but the pic is 300px and the text is 700px, so overflow issues are expected.

Setting the width of the text to 370px and float:left is one solution.

Comment: Removed the <P> tag, still same thing in IE11

Comment: No, if i do that the continuing text will not fill the hole 700px (I know the text aint that long in this example, but there might be text under the picture that should fill the 700px)

Comment: @user2192013 I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of div's/floats/displays. If you want your image as just an inline-block element, then don't wrap it inside a `<div>` floating left. The image should then just be placed inside the `<div id="text">` block and you'll get your expected behavior.

Comment: I agree with @BradM. `#text+#pic=1000px` and `#container=700px`, 700<1000, therefore it breaks the layout. +1